# iOS - Can I put Google Ads or Apple iAds on an app that is not on the App Store?

Tags: ios, swift

I worked on an app for a client that is not going to be on App Store but the company is going to have their customers use it everyday.  Can I put Google Ads or Apple iAds on it without it being on the App Store?

Best,
A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the legal side of it, but from my experience of publishing an app that uses both iAds and Google Ads (AdMob), you won't be able to use iAds because they go through an approval process that's started automatically when the app goes live on the App Store.

However, you can use AdMob ads in an app that's not in the App Store. However, as noted previously, I don't know if there are any legal issues.

Comment: Thank you, Joesph, this is very helpful :D :D